# LINQ Select query using ternary Operator

Tags: c#, linq

I'm not able to get the specific element from the list based on below condition, can someone help me out here

```
string Text = List.Any(x => x.IsnonConcurrent) ? coverage.Quotes
            .Where(x=>Number == quote.Number).Select(x=>quote.Description)
            .ToList()
            .ToString() + Details : coverage.Description + Details;
```

I see SYSTEM.COLLECTIONS.GENERIC.LIST`1[SYSTEM.STRING] in the output instead of element Name

Comment: You're calling `ToString` on a list (that you got from calling `ToList`). However, list doesn't override `ToString()` so you are getting back the default implementation.

Comment: `.ToList().ToString()` this calls ToString on the whole list. Do you want to concatenate the items of this list ?

Comment: `ToList()` will return list and `ToList().ToString()` will return `SYSTEM.COLLECTIONS.GENERIC.LIST`1[SYSTEM.STRING` that's why you are seeing this output. What exact output do you want?

Comment: Just because you can get everything onto one line doesn't mean you should. Teneray if's should be avoided in complex statements like this. [Good programmers write code that humans can understand](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Martin_Fowler#:~:text=Any%20fool%20can%20write%20code,code%20that%20humans%20can%20understand.)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked

```
string Text = List.Any(x => x.IsnonConcurrent) ? coverage.Quotes
            .Where(x=>Number == quote.Number).Description + Details : coverage.Description + Details;
```

Answer (score -1):

However your code statement is not right.But you can try with following code

```
string Text = List.Any(x => x.IsnonConcurrent) ? string.Join(" ", coverage.Quotes.Where(x => Number == x.Number).Select(x => x.Description).ToList()) + Details : coverage.Description + Details;
```

Comment: [my eyes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62301968/linq-select-query-using-ternary-operator#comment110186853_62301968). Also you need to explain **what** you've done and **why**.

Comment: @Liam Question was not about what and why.

Comment: The question is **always** about what and why.